# Unable to have Flash Component (SWC) access the library in live preview

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, components

I am building a set of Flash components with the ability to replace the skin of the component with another one in the library.

Currently, I am able to access the library after running the application, but not during live preview and I'd like to know if it is possible for the component to access the library while running in live preview mode (the mode where you can drag the component around the stage and change its properties in the Component Parameters window)

Here is a simplified code that just looks to see if there is a symbol of the name specified and than instantiates it and adds it as a child.

```
package 
{
    import fl.core.UIComponent;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.system.ApplicationDomain;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Roy Lazarovich
     */
    public class CompTest extends UIComponent 
    {
        private var customfile  :String;

        public function CompTest()
        {

        }

        override protected function configUI():void
        {

        }

        override protected function draw():void
        {
            super.draw();
        }

        private function setCustomFile():void
        {
            if (ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.hasDefinition(customfile))
            {
                var c:Class = Class(ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.getDefinition(customfile));
                var mc:MovieClip = new c();
                addChild(mc);
            }
        }

        [Inspectable(name = "_Custom File", defaultValue = "")]
        public function set _customfile(value:String):void
        {
            customfile = value;
            setCustomFile();

            drawNow();
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you include the libraries in your path?

Comment: Do you mean including the location of the client library in the paths for the component? I'm not sure that's totally feasible -- we have a couple hundred client libraries that use our components.

Or do you mean including the client path in client .fla ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you have already tried to fix this situation. But hopefully this might help.

Right click on the MovieClip in your library, select Linkage and give it a class name, ie. MyThing.

In your code,

```
newMyThing = new MyThing();
this.addChild(newMyThing);
trace("tada!");
```

Hope that helps or gets you closer to a solution.

Comment: "MyThing" is not known at publish time, it is set as a property on the component. At best, you'd use `getDefinitionByName`, however it fails.

When publishing the .fla using the component, it works fine. The problem lies in the Live Preview of the component not being able to instantiate from the .fla's library into the Live Preview on the stage in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in LivePreview, as long as I apply it in configUI, and not draw:

```
public class EditableBitmap extends UIComponent 
{
    protected var placeholder:String = "None";
    protected var bitmap:Bitmap;
    protected var scale:Number = 1;

    [Inspectable(name = "Placeholder", type = String, defaultValue="None")]
    public function set Placeholder($value:String):void 
    { 
        placeholder = $value;
        configUI();
    }
    public function get Placeholder():String { return placeholder; }

    public function EditableBitmap() 
    {
        //Console.Debug("NEW EditableBitmap");
        super();
    }

    override protected function configUI():void 
    {
        //Console.Debug("EditableBitmap configUI: " + width);
        if (!isNaN(width))
        {
            wDim = width;
            hDim = height;
            graphics.clear();
            graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 0.1);
            graphics.drawRect(0, 0, wDim, hDim);
        }
        if (placeholder != "None" && placeholder != "")
        {
            var asset:Class = getDefinitionByName(placeholder) as Class;
            var data:BitmapData = new asset() as BitmapData;
            bitmap = new Bitmap(data);
        }
        super.configUI();
    }

    override protected function draw():void 
    {
        if (bitmap)
        {
            addChild(bitmap);
            bitmap.x = off_x * scale;
            bitmap.y = off_y * scale;
            bitmap.scaleX = bitmap.scaleY = scale;
        } 
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** When I'm working on the FLA where I am editing the component, the bitmap is only displayed from the library inconsistenty. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. But when I export the SWC and then import the component to another movie, it works every time, in LivePreview as well as at runtime.

**UPDATE**
It seems this doesn't work in CS6 unless the symbol is already embedded in the component .SWC I wanted to see if I could trick it, by embedding one image in the SWC and then replacing it with another of the same name in the destination file. This didn't work, but it did point me to how you can do this:

[image]

So, it's a bit laborious, but you could work around this by:

1) Creating a dummy asset for each property in the component SWC.
2) Overriding this using a custom class in the file where you deploy the component

... all of which may be more trouble than it's worth, but which should provide a solution to the problem.

Comment: As soon as I am able to test this, I will report back with my findings. Thank you for posting it. It is possible that my test code (it looks similar, but slightly different to yours) simply fails when it comes to fonts.

Comment: Let me know what you find - more details might narrow it down to another solution. LivePreview can be a bit flaky, but in my experience usually only when you're authoring the component, not once it's published to a swc.

Comment: I'm trying to replicate what you've done here. My components aren't inheriting from the stock UIComponent or UIObject since they need to run on a console and those are a little heavy for it.  Of course, my need is for fonts, and that's not working. I'm trying to track down what's different/missing. My versions of UIComponent and UIObject don't have a configUI function. Is yours based on the standard UIComponent? AS2 or AS3?

Comment: Nevermind, I was looking at the wrong ones. I was looking at mx.core not fl.core. Will report back.

Comment: I've tried to duplicate your example, using the same code as yours. I've added a png to my target library and exported it for AS with a valid identifier, I've added the SWC component, an instance of the component on the stage, and set Placeholder to the png's identifier. However nothing appears.

I am using CS6, I don't know if that matters. Hopefully it doesn't, because I don't think we've got access to any other versions.

Comment: In CS6 it only seems to work if the Placeholder symbol is embedded in the SWC - that is, the component seems to access its own library in LivePreview, not that of the parent document. I haven't got older versions installed to run a check, but I think this has changed from CS5 (or at least CS4, which is when I wrote that component code).

Comment: Aw crap. There's no real way for us to go backward since Adobe (and most elsewhere) won't sell us an older version, and we already have all these CS6 licenses. >_<  I guess I have to try the RSL loaded by both SWC and parent document method somehow. That's gonna be hell with paths.

Comment: What's odd is that the parent domain of the component in live preview isn't the domain of the destination document, so this doesn't work: `var context:ApplicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
    if (ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.parentDomain != null) context = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.parentDomain;
    var asset:Class = context.getDefinition(placeholder) as Class;`

Comment: You might also be able to do it by embedding a custom live preview swf, which loads a bitmap from the current domain. I haven't got time to test that. You've probably already seen these docs, which are old, but comprehensive on the component model: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/creating_as3_components.html   Good luck - and post back here if you find a fix for this.